# Sync system time between Windows PC and Linux Device

Tags: ssh, timestamp, ubuntu-18.04, putty

I am using a Windows laptop running Windows 10 to ssh, using putty, into an Odroid XU4 running Ubuntu 18.04. When the ssh connection is established, I use putty to modify a few files on the Odroid. However, the system time for the Odroid is much different than that of my Windows laptop and the timestamps get really screwed up. There is no internet or RTC backup battery for the Odroid, so the time always resets when it is powered off. Is there a way to set the date and time of my Odroid to that of my Windows computer so the system times match up?

Comment: You'd be better off setting up an NTP service like `chrony` or the older `ntp` package to sync the time on boot.

Comment: Doesn't ntp require access to the internet to sync with its server? Would I be able to use any of these solutions for my Odroid, which does not have internet access?

Comment: It's possible to run a local NTP server on your laptop or on your network.  It wouldn't be very reliable, but you just need kinda close, not terrific accuracy.  SSH itself doesn't provide this functionality.

Comment: Ah ok. So I would run the local NTP server on my laptop and then use ssh to pull the system time into my Odroid?

Comment: Yup, that would work.